# MutableStateFlow and combine emit the initial value of state, but public state is update?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

I am currently trying to update my state inside a view model. Currently, the public state is being updated accordingly, but the private state only emits the initial state. I am using a MutableStateFlow and combine because I have two functions that get data from the local SQL Delight database.

Here is the code I am talking about

```
private val _state = MutableStateFlow(StudyFlashcardsUiState())
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)


    val state = combine(
        _state,
        database.getAllSetCards(setId),
        database.getSetAsFlow(setTitle)
    ) { privateState, list, set ->
        privateState.copy(
            set = set,
            cards = list,
            currentCard = privateState.currentCard ?: list.first(),
            currentIndex = if (privateState.currentIndex == -1) 0 else privateState.currentIndex,
        )

    }.stateIn(
        scope = scope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(300L),
        initialValue = StudyFlashcardsUiState()
    )
```

Here is the data class for the state if needed:

```
data class StudyFlashcardsUiState(
    val set: VocabSet = VocabSet("", MR.images.cat_icon, setId = 0, expanded = false, isPrivate = SetMode.PUBLIC, dateCreated = null),
    val cards: List<UiFlashcard> = emptyList(),
    val currentCard: UiFlashcard? = null,
    val currentIndex: Int = -1,
    val showBack: Boolean = false,
    val isComplete: Boolean = false,
    val experienceGained: Long = 0,
    val uiError: StudyError? = null
)
```

When the code runs, the combine block successfully retrieves the data from the SQL, it updates the public state. The issue is that the private _state still has the initial value of StudyFlashcardsUiState().

Any advice on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your `_state` is never updated, so its value doesn't change. Actually your `state` created by `stateIn` is not backed by the private `MutableStateFlow`, so it could be a regular `var` instead.

```
private var privateState = StudyFlashcardsUiState()
val state = combine(
        database.getAllSetCards(setId),
        database.getSetAsFlow(setTitle)
    ) { list, set ->
        val newState = privateState.copy(
            set = set,
            cards = list,
            currentCard = privateState.currentCard ?: list.first(),
            currentIndex = if (privateState.currentIndex == -1) 0 else privateState.currentIndex,
        )
        privateState = newState
        newstate
    }.stateIn(
        scope = scope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(300L),
        initialValue = StudyFlashcardsUiState()
    )
```

Comment: I don’t think `_state` should be a MutableStateFlow at all. It should just be a `var` directly holding the type. Your code above will work, but the lambda will always run an extra redundant time because it changes the value of one of its own source flows.

Comment: Thanks, updated. `_state` should've never been in `combine` @Tenfour04